# Can I do mAdserve integration for Sencha Touch 2 apps?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I just downloaded mAdserve and was willing to try it out with my Sencha Touch 2 application.  Unfortunately, it only comes bundles with SDKs for Andriod and iOS. How can I take advantage of this with Sencha Touch or HTML5 apps in general?